# how to fix child window on browser scroll without hard coded javascript?

Tags: javascript, extjs, dashboard, childwindow

I have Ext Js application. Left side I have menu and right side Dashboard(portal style). On menu click I open every new window(part) on dashboard. 
Lest say every new window(part) is new module in my application so I have grids, panels, navigation buttons inside.

Now I have problem with child window. when I open child window inside this module window it's ok. when I am trying to move this child window from it's parent it's impossible and it's ok. but If I open many parts on my screen browser makes scroll and child windows moves on scroll and escapes from parent.

Can someone help me? how to fix child window on browser scroll without hard coded javascript?

Comment: You may want to show a fiddle demonstrating your problem.

Comment: And how to do that? I just want to fix window inside of parent and don't escape from there on whatever happens

Comment: ok I have got it. Problem is that on browser scroll windows(any) always stays on it's view position(and not absolute position). now I need config to set true/false to remove this functionality but I still can't  find which is this config param.

Comment: I will say it one last time: [Make a fiddle demonstrating your problem](https://fiddle.sencha.com/).

Comment: The other possibility is that you [search the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/) for yourself. Don't worry if you don't find anything, it's completely possible that the config you are searching does not exist.

Comment: look this url https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11kf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fix window in it's absolute position and don't scroll on browser scroll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911019/how-to-fix-window-in-its-absolute-position-and-dont-scroll-on-browser-scroll)

Comment: no add several fieldsets while makes scroll and than add window somewere in fieldset. than scroll and will see windows not stays out of screen an moves down as you scroll