# how to fix window in it's absolute position and don't scroll on browser scroll?

Tags: extjs, scroll, position, window

In ExtJS when I scroll browser window Ext.window.window stays on same position on Viewport. I would like to fix this window on it's absolute position.
I saw documentation says:

> fixed : Boolean
>   Configure as true to have this Component fixed at its X, Y coordinates in the browser viewport, immune to scrolling the document.
>
> Defaults to: false

But does not work for me. What I am missing? How to fix window in it's absolute position and don't scroll on browser scroll?

Comment: Please create a sencha fiddle. Will help to understand better

Comment: check this url. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11kf

Comment: when I set fixed: true, it works. right? The window is at same position, even page is scrolled.

Comment: click left menu several times while right panel makes scroll. and than click "add window" button. I know the problem is fixed height of panel. but this is my layout

Comment: No I want fixed: false and not works

Comment: I want that window move and not stay on same position

Comment: Do you want to be able to move the window over the whole page?

Answer (score 1):

This part works. But still, are you concerned about constrain?

```
 handler: function(button){
                                var w = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                                    height: 150,
                                    width: 200,                                        
                                    renderTo: button.up('fieldset').getEl().dom,
                                    title: 'child window'                                      
                                });

                                this.up('fieldset').add(w);
                                w.show();
                            }
```

Comment: thanks this line renderTo: button.up('fieldset').getEl().dom,  "super" works. but I have another problem. I leave constrain: true and window which added is not in center

Answer (score 0):

Like this maybe:

```
handler: function(){
    var w = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        height: 150,
        width: 200,
        title: 'child window',
    });

    this.up('fieldset').add(w);
    w.show();
}
```